# nginx on Ubuntu: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, debian, puppet, vagrant

I am new to system administration. After installing nginx [via puppet](https://github.com/kasperisager/puppet-nginx) on Ubuntu I get the following output:

```
[alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)

[warn] 1898#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

[emerg] 1898#0: open() "/var/log/nginx/access.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

How do I get rid of all of these messages?

I don't want to use command line directly (chown / chmod) and repeat it every time I create a new server. Therefore, I am thinking of what has to be added to the puppet manifest.

What is the best sysadmin practice in this case: to change owner / permissions for /var/log/nginx or to store logs in different location? If chown / chmod is the way to go, which specific permissions would ensure the highest level of security?

I tried this, but it didn't help:

```
  file { '/var/log/nginx':
    ensure  => directory,
    mode    => '0755',
    owner   => 'www-data',
    group   => 'www-data',
    recurse => true
  }
```

Edited:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ ps aux | grep [n]ginx
root      1001  0.0  0.1  62908  1388 ?        Ss   08:47   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data  1002  0.0  0.1  63260  1696 ?        S    08:47   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  1003  0.0  0.1  63260  1696 ?        S    08:47   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  1004  0.0  0.1  63260  1696 ?        S    08:47   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  1005  0.0  0.1  63260  1696 ?        S    08:47   0:00 nginx: worker process

vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/nginx;
vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo chmod -R 755 /var/log/nginx;
vagrant@precise64:~$ ls -l /var/log/nginx/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 214 Sep 10 11:07 error.log
```

Comment: You shouldn't focus on 'magically getting rid of the errors'. Read them, understand them, Google them and learn about them. Fix the problem that they're telling you about.

Comment: "Permission denied" is the key here, on the file /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: I tried to fix permissions before posting this question, but this didn't solve the problem:
`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/nginx;
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/log/nginx;
ls -l /var/log/nginx/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 214 Sep 10 11:07 error.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[this](https://serverfault.com/questions/370337/run-nginx-as-a-non-root-user) could help you.

The messages you are receiving are dued to the fact that you started nginx as non-root user or without using **sudo**.

To get rid of log dir error, you have to check which user nginx is running as and give the appropriate permissions to that folder ( your puppet rule maybe gave rights to the wrong one )

The warning message you reported is triggered by the fact that ( as warning states ) "user" directive is meant to be used ONLY when your nginx master process is running as root.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but this usually has to do with SELinux. Try setting it to permissive and it'll probably work fine.